# Swift Package Manager: Local Packages cross dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have 3 different local packages inside my main project. The names are:

1. EnumsPackage
2. ExtensionsPackage
3. NetworkingPackage

Now, NetworkingPackage needs certain methods that are declared in EnumsPackage and ExtensionsPackage.

I am not able to create a local dependency inside NetworkingPackage.

Also, I have a team working, so I have to push the code and that should run in another system as well ( as such, I don't think giving local path of Enum and Extensions Package inside Networking Package will make sense)

[image]

Comment: could you show the Package.swift of the NetworkingPackage where you try to specify local dependencies? what is the error that you get?